# reference to table range in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import my data from Excel to SQL. I wrote some code - when I used `Set rng = Application.Range"F5:H10")` it works.
However, I want to use a table since the amount of data changes every time. How can I use an Excel table in this part of my code?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't need the header, you can use `Set rng = Range("Table1")`.  Just replace `Table1` with the name of your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
Sub Table2Range()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range
    MsgBox rng.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

**Note:**

You get the header as well as the data-body.

Comment: Also can use `ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange` to get only the data range.